# Read data from USART

Tags: windows, embedded, arm, usart

I am programming an ARM Cortex M3. I have stdout functions operating on the USART port. How should I monitor the data sent through USART by my board on my Windows 7 computer? Is there standard "USART packet sniffers" I should use?

Comment: there are many programs, hyperterm, putty, etc.  Or just write your own.

Comment: It probably does not affect the answer, but Cortex-M3 describes only the core architecture of your microcontroller, the USART is defined by the specific chip manufacturer and will differ between chips and chip vendors.  So if it matters at all, you should specify the part you are using when asking specifically about on-chip peripheral components.

Comment: As dwelch mentioned, you just need a terminal program (I prefer teraterm).  However, between the Cortex chip and the PC you will need a RS232 to TTL signal level converter.  This may (or may not) be on your board.  If it's not on your board, you buy an adapter like this: http://www.serialcomm.com/serial_rs232_converters/rs232_rs485_to_ttl_converters.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monitoring serial port I/O in windows involves installing software that sits between the serial port driver and your application.  There are a number of tools that do this, varying in utility, compatibility and cost:

- [Portmon](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1332164329&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=technet%24technet%24technet&wreply=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644&lc=1033&id=254354&mkt=en-US)
- [HDD Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/)
- [Eltima Serial Port Monitor](http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/serialmonitor)
- [CommFront 232Anayzer](http://www.232analyzer.com/232default.htm)
- [AGG Advanced Serial Port Monitor](http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-port-monitor.htm)
- [SerialMon](http://www.serialmon.com/)
- [... and more ...](https://www.google.com/search?q=serial%20port%20monitor)